# Monitoring (and automatically restarting) services on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I have a home server running TrueNAS Core. Inside a Jail, I have Plex mediaserver running so I can easily view my photos on my TV. Due to some bug in Plex, it sometimes crashes when I add new pictures. Of course this'll get fixed eventually, but until then I want to set something up so that Plex will automatically start again after it crashes.

I have tried setting up daemontools, but none of the guides I followed resulted in Plex automatically restarting. I think this is because I have Plex setup as a service instead of running a single script to start it.

Is there a way to monitor certain services on FreeBSD, and automatically restart them when they go down? I've searched everywhere I know but my queries yield no useful results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to monitor certain services on FreeBSD, and automatically restart them when they go down?

There is an open source program called Monit:

> Monit is a utility for managing and monitoring processes, files,
> directories, devices and network services on a Unix system. Monit
> conducts automatic maintenance and repair and can execute meaningful
> causal actions in error situations.
>
> monit supports:
>
> - Daemon mode - poll services at a specified interval  -Group and manage groups of services, service dependencies
> - Logging - syslog or own logfile
> - **Alert, start, stop and restart of services based on it's characteristics**
> - MD5 and SHA1 checksums
> - Runtime Unix socket and TCP/IP port checking (TCP and UDP)
> - Process status, timeout, memory and cpu usage, etc.
> - Device usage monitoring (inodes and space)
> - File monitoring (timestamp, checksum, permission, owner, etc.)
> - Directory monitoring (timestamp, permission, owner, etc.)
> - Remote network services monitoring (ping, response time, protocol, etc.)
> - System load average monitoring
> - Flexible and customizable email alert messages and notifications
> - Protocol verification such as HTTP, FTP, SMTP, POP, IMAP, NNTP, NTP, etc.
> - A HTTP interface with XML output option

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [FreshPorts -- sysutils/monit: Unix system management and proactive monitoring](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/monit)

It can be downloaded from [Easy, proactive monitoring of processes, programs, files, directories, filesystems and hosts | Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/), where it states:

> Monit is a small Open Source utility for managing and monitoring Unix systems. Monit conducts automatic maintenance and repair and can execute meaningful causal actions in error situations.

...

> **Both FreeBSD and OpenBSD include Monit packages.**

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: I found Monit a bit hard to set up. I used `supervisord` instead, which I liked more.